# @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity() in entity - how can I passover this with an doctrine event

Tags: php, forms, symfony, events, doctrine

there is a product entity like this:

```
/**
 * Class Product.
 *
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity("itemNumber")
 * 
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    private $itemNumber;
    .
    .
    .
```

But in some case I want override this "unique" behaviour.
I need this override on the form level. At the database level, the unique behavior should be preserved. I would like to achieve that with a form event the article number gets a prefix. Something like this:

```
/**
 * Class BaseProductEventListener.
 */
class ProductCreateListener
{   
    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getObject();

        if (!$entity instanceof Product) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$entity->getCategories() instanceof ArrayCollection) {
            return;
        }

        if (isset($entity->getCategories()[0])) {
            $firstCat = $entity->getCategories()[0];

            if ($firstCat->getNameSlug() == 'my_nameslug') {
                $entity->setItemNumber('my_prefix_'.$entity->getItemNumber());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So If my product has a specific category the itemnumber will get a prefix on database level.

The problem is, that my event will fire AFTER the entity Assert:
@DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity("itemNumber")

How can I change it that my event changes the article number first and the entity assertion is checked later in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it at the form level, you can always add a form event listener. Example:

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();
                //// your logic here ...

})
```

This intercepts the data before it's submitted by the form, well before the Doctrine persist event.

Form events [docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).